# How can i mage my nav bar more even and how can i cut down on some code? (thank you for the formatting help)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

[My code and site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaDQ8.png)

For some reason the text on the right of the nav bar is way closer to the middle than the one on the left and i also feel like most of the flex ive added is unnecessa

```css
body {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

Header {
    background-color: palevioletred;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex:1 0 0;
} 
li{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex:1 0 0;

    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='style.css' type='text/css' <head>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li><h2>main</h2> </li>
            <li><h2>main</h2> </li>
            <li><h1>Welcome</h1></li>
            <li><h2>main</h2> </li>
            <li><h2>main</h2> </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
```

ry, how can avoid that in the future ?

Comment: Hello @Emrekse. Please insert your code here as a snippet by editing your question and pressing Ctrl+M.

Comment: Could you add the code to the post and also link to a https://jsfiddle.net/ project to make it easier to help.

Comment: Don't link to the jsfiddle.net project, just add the code directly into the snippet functionality on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose you this solution:

```css
body{
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header{
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  padding: 0; /*ADD => remove space (tabulation) before <li> block*/
}

li{
  /*display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;*/ /*REMOVE*/
  flex: 1 0 0;
  list-style: none; /*REMOVE point before title*/
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
  <ul>
  <li><h2>main</h2></li>
  <li><h2>main</h2></li>  
  <li><h1>Welcome</h1></li>
  <li><h2>main</h2></li>
  <li><h2>main</h2></li>
  </ul>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however warnt the flex elements supposed to rid me of needing to use width in the nav menu ? İ was thinking that with flex grow they would automatically space eachother and if we add a 20% width value would there be any value left for the flex grows ? (sorry if it sounds rude not my intention)

Comment: Oh yes, I understand, no worries. In this case you'll just have to follow Itjfansite's code and add the padding:0; in the CSS ul if you want to remove the space on the left side of the line. I will edit my code in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Removing this bit of code form the li seemed to of fixed it

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
```

```css
body {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

Header {
    background-color: palevioletred;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex:1 0 0;
} 
li{
    list-style: none;
    flex:1 0 0;

    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='style.css' type='text/css' <head>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li><h2>main</h2> </li>
            <li><h2>main</h2> </li>
            <li><h1>Welcome</h1></li>
            <li><h2>main</h2> </li>
            <li><h2>main</h2> </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
```